# Is it possible to upload image files from 2 different inputs fields?

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm trying to upload images from 2 different input fields. Is it even possible to send images from 2 different inputs?

**Below is my multer code I tried:**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./views/img/temp_folder");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  }
});

const fileFilter = function(req, file, cb) {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: fileFilter
}).array(
  { name: "imgs_to_upload", maxCount: 12 },
  { name: "main_img", maxCount: 1 }
);
```

**And here is my HTML/PUG code:**

```
div(class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9")
form(action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data")
h3 Dodaj naslov članka
div(class="form-group")
input(type="text", name="title" placeholder="Naslov clanka" class="form-control" required)
h3 Dodaj predopis članka
div(class="form-group")
textarea(rows="10" name = "pretext")
h3 Dodaj tekst članka
div(class="form-group")
textarea(rows="20" name = "text")
div(class="form-group")
input(type="file" name = "imgs_to_upload" multiple id = "slike")
div(class="form-group")
input(type="file" name = "main_img" multiple id = "slike")
div(class="form-group" id = "button-holder")
input(type="Submit" value = "Dodaj" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "submitButton")
```

Comment: Yep possible but please share some code or what do you want to achieve so I can help

Comment: There you go. If you need more just tell me.